# What causes enum.ToString() to intern the member it represents

Tags: c#, memory-management, enums, tostring

I've been looking into the effects of calling `.ToString()` on enum members -- more specifically whether it creates a new string object or not.

Consider the following enum definition:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    MyValue = 0,
    MyOtherValue = 1
}
```

If I execute the following code with breakpoints on `x`, `y` and `z` and take a heap dump at each point

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyEnum));

    var x = MyEnum.MyValue.ToString(); // Breakpoint 1
    var y = MyEnum.MyValue.ToString(); // Breakpoint 2
    var z = MyEnum.MyOtherValue.ToString(); // Breakpoint 3

    Console.WriteLine(x, y, z);
}
```

I can see the following results:

```
| Stage   | # string objects |
|---------|------------------|
| Initial | 463              |
| BP 1    | 465              |
| BP 2    | 465              |
| BP 3    | 466              |
```

I looked through [enum.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,1365cfeffd45409d,references) but couldn't find what causes the (lack of?) allocations.

1. What causes the two allocations at the first breakpoint?
2. Why didn't the second call cause an allocation? I don't see any lookups in the string pool and I don't expect these enum names to be interned since they are are retrieved through an invocation of a virtual method which uses reflection to find it.
3. By manually inspecting the string values on the heap at each snapshot I can see that step 1 adds "MyValue", step 2 does not add anything and step 3 adds "MyOtherValue".

The overarching question is why `Enum.ToString()` seems to intern the member it represents. What part of the code causes the interning?

Comment: If you want to know why the code does what it does, just look at the source code for that method.

Comment: Aren't all strings interned?

Comment: @NicStrong No, only compile time literal strings (or strings that are explicitly interned).  And even then, that's just the default behavior.

Comment: @Servy I thought I adequately demonstrated that I looked through the entire callchain but didn't see anything that could explain the results I saw by measuring it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel So you didn't notice the method to get the cached string values, or the code that gets the string from that cache?  It's pretty prominent in the code.  You had to have looked through all of those methods calls before you found the code to actually compute the value (since it's a part of the cache construction).  In fact, the actual code to compute the names for the values is an external method, so just about the *only* code shown there is the code to cache it.

Comment: @Servy I assume you're talking about `GetEnumData`? Where does the caching actually happen?

Comment: `GetCachedValuesAndNames`

Comment: @Servy For a non `[Flags]` attributed enum I am having trouble finding the path that calls `GetCachedValuesAndNames`. It seems to jump in to `Type.GetEnumNames()` and I don't see where that ever gets back to the cache.

Comment: @Servy That would indeed be a cache. How is this called though? I don't see it used anywhere in the chain if you follow the [`public override String ToString()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,795) method. That cache method you refer to suddenly ends up in `rttype`. This does indeed contain a method `public override string GetEnumName(object value)` which is the one that calls the cached method but how do we end up there in the first place?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain For the non-flags path it gets the string from the field's name, and the field info for a type is cached.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `ToString -> Enum.InternalFormat -> InternalFlagsFormat -> GetCachedValuesAndNames`

Comment: That explains it then :) I'm not using a `[Flags]` enum and the `GetFields()` method was my only thought of where the caching could happen